# Creating a second sandbox in chat

Tags: discussion, chat

I am working on creating a chatbot, and right now I am in the process of creating a room-specific feature. (Meaning the data stored only applies to a given room). In order to test that it actually works, I need to use multiple rooms. However, when I write this post, there is only one room where essentially testing and a lot of "unconstructive" messages can be sent. The Sandbox room.

So could it be an idea to create a second sandbox for this kind of testing to avoid having sand outside the sandbox?(pun intended)

---

The discussion tag is added because of the warning when creating the room: `there should not be several rooms with identical topics.` - So I came here to ask if it is OK to create it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, if you have the ability to create a chatroom you can define how it is to be used.

SOCVR has their own room for [testing](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68414/socvr-testing-facility) and so have [others](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124882/bot-test).

So either find an existing room that is open for bot testing or create your own room. If you want the room to be only used by you and your bot you can put the room in Gallery mode so you can control who has write access.

If you only plan for having a few tests, joining an existing room is preferred but if the purpose of the room is to support a wider test or audience I see not much harm in creating a dedicated sandbox room for chatbots.

Comment: I just wanted to clear it before I created it, because of the "there should not be several rooms with identical topics" warning. Thanks for the answer though. (Accepting in 5 minutes, can't do it now because of a warning)

Comment: Pretty much what I was going to say but I'd also make the room title/description clear as to its purpose and obviously make sure the bot behaves itself.

Comment: @JonClements Will do. Making sure the bot behaves is not going to be a problem.